# Sass Error: can't find stylesheet to import when @use-ing MDC Web's button using Gulp

Tags: css, sass, gulp, mdc-components, material-components-web

I have these two lines of code in my `main.scss` as required by the [MDC Web's docs](https://material.io/components/buttons/web#using-buttons).

```
@use "@material/button";
@include button.core-styles;
```

Then, I have this Gulp task to convert my `main.scss` file to a single `build.css` file. My `main.scss` file compiles just fine when I remove the two lines above.

The error I am getting is the following.

```
Message:
    src\styles\main.scss
Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
1 │ @use "@material/button";
  │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

My Gulp task is the following.

```
gulp.task('css', ['clean:css'], function() {
  return gulp.src('src/styles/main.scss')
    .pipe(isDist ? through() : plumber())
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 versions'], cascade: false }))
    .pipe(isDist ? csso() : through())
    .pipe(rename('build.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/build'))
    .pipe(connect.reload());
});
```

I am using `gulp-dart-sass` to compile the `.scss` files. How can I fix the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are using `package.json`,  **material-components-web** is added to dependencies and dependencies are installed. Then it looks like you need to add **node_modules** to load paths for Sass to look for imports:

```
...
     .pipe(sass({ includePaths: ['node_modules'] }).on('error', sass.logError))
...
```

Comment: Yes, that is right: I am using MDC-web's node packages and I have them listed as dependencies in my `package.json`.